# raspberry pi 3 + windows 10 iot changing password makes device inacessible

Tags: raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

- I downloaded the raspi image from MS.
- I have the issue where my computer thinks my admin is blocking the iot dashboard so I used the dism workaround to flash the sd card.
- Device boots with defaults and I can log in via powershell as detailed in the MS docs. Administrator/p@ssw0rd
- I change machine name using

`set computername mycoolname`

- Then I create a new account for myself and add it to the local admin group.
- Then I change the default admin password and reset.

When the raspi comes back up the hostname is still minwinpc and neither the built in admin account or the new one I created will work. 
I tried the default password and the one I changed it to.

Anyone else have these issues? Ive tried waiting on the device to settle in, as others have reported that it can take time. Its not making a difference.

Comment: Your question is very off topic for SO which is a site for asking questions about programming problems. Instead, you should delete this and ask on the RaspberryPi stack exchange listed at the bottom of this page.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: It seems device name didn't change successfully. You need reboot device let the new device name take effort first.

Comment: It seems can't change device name successfully on version 10.0.17744.1001. Did you use this version?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I am using the latest version available. Sorry, I cant check it at the moment.

Comment: @Rob Powershell is code, right? And that code isn't working, so it is a coding issue.

Comment: Powershell is a shell, not code. You show no code which also makes this off topic. Your question is about server setup and configuration which is also off topic. Thus, you need to go elsewhere as I suggested. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @JohnS Have you tried the answer to see if it helps?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the wrong command "set computername mycoolname". You need use "[setcomputername](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/connect-your-device/powershell#commonly-used-powershell-commands) mycoolname".

I do the following tests on the latest version 10.0.17763.1 and all work for me.

It will give the result of changing name like this:

[image]

Change password. No need reboot for password change.

[image]

For adding a user, for example:

```
net user rita windowsiot /add

net localgroup Administrators rita /add
```

Check the user added:

```
net localgroup administrators
```

[image]

Use the newly added user "rita" to login:

[image]